# Realizar Busqueda entre fechas. Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

Buenas Tardes,

Estoy realizando un query sencillo de un logico en db2 que es tipo numerico pero contiene fechas del siguiente formato 20170831, pero al realizar el query tanto con 'between' tanto con los operadores '>= <=' trae todas las fechas existentes.

El query es el siguiente

```
SELECT NROP55, TIPL55, PBAE55, STAT1B, FIPL55 from 
IVRDB2.S103V5HM.xxxx.xxxx 
WHERE Fecha >=  20170801 AND Fecha <= 20170829 
ORDER BY FIPL55 desc
```

El formato es año, mes, dia y el resultado siempre es del año 2014 o mas alla.

Me podrian ayudar?

(Ya use las comillas para las fechas pero aun arroja el mismo resultado)
Saludos

Comment: Hola hans, Fecha que tipo de dato es?  timestamp, date?

Comment: según la pregunta, es numérico. Pero sería bueno que pongas el tipo de dato exacto de la columna `Fecha`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas usar las comillas simples en tu busqueda:

```
SELECT NROP55, TIPL55, PBAE55, STAT1B, FIPL55 
FROM IVRDB2.S103V5HM.xxxx.xxxx 
WHERE Fecha >=  '20170801' AND Fecha <= '20170829' 
ORDER BY FIPL55 desc**
```

Comment: Ya use las comillas y el resultado es igual

Comment: mm Fecha de que tipo es, numeric!?

Answer (score 1):

Si la columna fecha es de tipo char (quiero suponer eso), podrías usar formatos en las fechas, como por ejemplo:

```
SELECT NROP55, TIPL55, PBAE55, STAT1B, FIPL55 <br>
From IVRDB2.S103V5HM.xxxx.xxxx 
WHERE Convert(char(10),Fecha,121) Between '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-29' 
ORDER BY FIPL55 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Si la columna fecha es de un tipo numerico podrías probar con esta query a ver si es lo que estas buscando .

```
SELECT NROP55, TIPL55,PBAE55,STAT1B,FIPL55,
FROM IVRDB2.S103v5HM.xxxx.xxxx
WHERE Fecha BETWEEN 20170801 AND 20170829
ORDER BY FIPL55 DESC
```

Espero que te sirva , un saludo.